# How to get output of `all` effect?

Tags: redux-saga

I am trying to use saga outside the context of redux, simply experimenting with effects and generators.

I need to retrieve all key values from `Storage` in parallel, here is my implementation:

```
export function* getHeaders() {
  let calls = []
  APIClient.instance().keys.forEach((key) => calls.push(call(Storage.get, key)))
  yield all(calls)  
}
```

where each `Storage.get` returns a promise.

I do call the function as:

```
let values = getHeaders().next().value
console.log(values)
```

I already have 5 keys in storage, I expected to get their values, but instead I got:

[image]

Any idea?
as seen above, `uid` is the first key in `APIClient.instance().keys`

Comment: You basically need to build an interpreter that would take effect description and evaluate them. For example `ALL` could be a `Promise.all` on running interpreter on payload items, `CALL` should actually invoke the function and resolve a promise if returned, etc.

Comment: Do you have any example please?

Comment: Never tried it at home :)